# Multiple subtitles for hls

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

I'm trying to create hls playlist and multiple subtitles using ffmpeg with following command list:

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i sub1.srt -i sub2.srt -map 0:v -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -c:v:0 copy -c:s:0 webvtt -c:s:1 webvtt -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index.m3u8`

and I get this error:

```
Exactly one WebVTT stream is needed.
```

Is there a possibility to add more than one subtitle to hls playlist?

Comment: FFmpeg allows only creating one WebVTT subtitle per output stream. The only variant that could work is if you have multiple audio streams (e.g. multiple languages) and output them as different streams (using the `-var_stream_map` flag). Then you could add one subtitle per audio stream.